# Can't Group DateTime by Hour or Dump Result Apache Pig

Tags: hadoop, bigdata, apache-pig

I'm working on a project that requires me to find the temporal average (e.g: hour, day, month) for multiple datasets and then do calculations on those averages. The issue I am running into is that Apache Pig will not group by the time nor dump the DateTime values. I've tried several solutions posted here on Stack Overlflow and elsewhere to no avail. I've also read over the documentation, and am unable to find a solution.

**Here is my code so far:**

```
data = LOAD 'TestData' USING PigStorage(',');

t_data = foreach data generate (chararray)$0 as date, (double)$305 as w_top, (double)$306 as t_top, (double)$310 as w_mid, (double)$311 as t_mid, (double)$315 as w_bot, (double)$316 as t_bot, (double)$319 as pressure;

times = FOREACH t_data GENERATE ToDate(date,'YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.s') as (date), w_top, t_top, w_mid, t_mid, w_bot, t_bot, pressure;



grp_hourly = GROUP times by GetHour(date);

average = foreach grp_hourly generate flatten(group), times.date, AVG(times.w_top), AVG(times.t_top), AVG(times.w_mid), AVG(times.t_mid), AVG(times.w_bot), AVG(times.t_bot);
```

**And some sample lines from the data:**

```
2011-01-06 15:00:00.0 ,0.07225,-11.36384,-0.045,-11.24599,0.036,-12.44104,1021.707
2011-01-06 15:00:00.1 ,0.09975,-11.34448,-0.0325,-11.26053,0.041,-12.45392,1021.694
2011-01-06 15:00:00.2 ,0.15375,-11.35576,-0.02975,-11.26536,0.01025,-12.44748,1021.407
2011-01-06 15:00:00.3 ,-0.00225,-11.42034,-0.03775,-11.28477,-0.013,-12.44429,1021.764
2011-01-06 15:00:00.4 ,0.01625,-11.33965,-0.0395,-11.27989,-0.0395,-12.42172,1021.484
```

**What I Currently Get as Output:**

I get a file with one average of every variable I feed into APACHE Pig without a date and time (most likely the average of each variable over the entire data set). I need them for each hour and to be printed with the output. Any tips would be appreciated. Sorry if my post is messy, I don't post to Stack Overflow often.

Comment: Tried it again with some varying date formats, and still no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date and time pattern string in `ToDate` doesn't exactly match your data. You have `YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.s` but your data looks like `2011-01-06 15:00:00.0`. You need to match the spaces in your data, and since your hours are on the 24 hour, you need to use `HH` instead of `hh`. Check out the documentation for [Java SimpleDateFormat class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). Try this pattern string instead:

```
times = FOREACH t_data GENERATE ToDate(date,'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.s ') as date;
```

To debug your code, try dumping right after creating the relation `times` instead of at the end since it seems like the problem is with `ToDate()`.

Comment: Thanks @savagedata. I tried your line of code but got the same error I got when formatting it differently. 

"HadoopVersion PigVersion UserId StartedAt FinishedAt Features
3.1.0 0.17.0 hadoop 2018-04-25 19:57:48 2018-04-25 19:57:54 UNKNOWN

Failed!

Failed Jobs:
JobId Alias Feature Message Outputs
job_local102692474_0001 data,t_data,times MAP_ONLY Message: Job failed! file:/tmp/temp594095505/tmp1511528542,

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "file:///home/hadoop/TestData"

Output(s):
Failed to produce result in 
"

Answer (score 0):

Savage's answer was correct. The issue I had in my code was a quotation mark that was too close to the date and time string. So instead of writing mine like this:

```
(date,'YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.s')
```

It should be written like this:

```
(date,'YYYY-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.s ')
```